# Flitering Search Results

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm working on a project that enables you to play a sound when a cell in a tableview is selected. To make things a bit easier, I've implemented a search function. Problem is, it's not working quite right. when you click on a result, the sound that plays comes from the original array, rather than the newly filtered one. I know my error lies somewhere in here, and I'd like a bit of help finding it.

```
//Create new Sound Object
Sounds *sound = nil;
//check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and     set the Sound object from the appropriate array
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    sound = [filteredSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    sound = [soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

//Configure the cell
[[cell textLabel]setText:[sound name]];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

 return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSString *selectedSoundFile = [[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:selectedSoundFile ofType:@"mp3"];


if(path){
   theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    [self.theAudio play];
}

  if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    [self.theAudio play];

}
```

}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the array in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *selectedSoundFile = [[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
```

if you are palying from search results then use `filteredSoundArray` instead `soundArray`..

The condition which you are playing on select should be played from the array which you are using to display in table view. But you are using the array that have all sounds.

change as follows in `didSelectRowIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSString *selectedSoundFile;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

selectedSoundFile = [[filteredSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
}else{
selectedSoundFile = [[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
}
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:selectedSoundFile ofType:@"mp3"];


if(path){
   theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

[self.theAudio play];
}
}
```

Comment: When I change NSString *selectedSoundFile = [[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name]; to NSString *selectedSoundFile = [[filteredSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];  I recieve an "NSRangeException" for an empty array.

Comment: The filtered sounds work just fine now! But I get the "NSRangeException" when I try to play a sound that I am not searching for.

Comment: Should I change NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:selectedSoundFile ofType:@"mp3"]; and theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; ? Because now, every button plays the same sound.

Comment: no need.. you will get the audio name from the array.. try to check whether u are getting the audio name correctly `selectedSoundFile`